# Металлическое изделие на стенах домов

Tags: названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как называется изделие, состоящее из трёх металлических трубок?

Comment: Тритруб. Шутка. Это обычный держатель для флагов, с чего вы взяли, что у него есть какое-то специальное название?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Металлический кронштейн для флагов.
 http://101flag.ru/podstavki/kronshtejny-dlya-flagov/